# Как собрать ear в Netbeans имея проект web application

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish

Как собрать ear в Netbeans имея проект web application.Ну и второй вопрос: всегда деплоил через Нетбинс, а сейчас требуется сделать это не средствами, интегрированными в IDE, а средствами сервера приложений. Не подскажите как решаются данные задачи?

Comment: Создайте прожект Приложение Enterprise. Как появится в списке прожектов щёлкните по нему правой кнопкой. В появившемся контекстном меню первым же пунктом будет "Добавить модуль Java EE..."

Comment: К glassfish-у есть очень неплохая документация и для разработчика и для админа. В самом простейшем случае архив с приложением ложится в определённую папку, например `D:\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\domain1\autodeploy`. Готовое приложение netbeans помещает в папку `dist` внутри папки прожекта. Так вот взять и скопировать из `dist` в `autodeploy`